# Obj-c: How to add a 2d C array to NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, ios10

I have a two dimensional array like such:

```
struct myStruct twoDarray[maxX][maxY];
```

I can iterate over the array and see that all values are properly assigned.
I'm trying to put this array into an NSData object like such:

```
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&twoDarray length:sizeof(struct myStruct) * actualX * actualY];
```

This assignment succeeds. `myData.length` shows the expected size (struct * x * y). The accepted answer on this question suggests this is the right syntax: [Is it possible to store 2D array in info.plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970144/is-it-possible-to-store-2d-array-in-info-plist)

Eventually, I try to read back the array with a loop:

```
int start = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < actualX; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < actualY; y++)
    {
        struct myStruct readBack
        [myData getBytes:&readBack range:NSMakeRange(start, sizeof(struct myStruct))];
        start += sizeof(struct myStruct)
     }
}
```

However, I only get valid data in the extraction loop when x = 0. If x = 0, all structures for all values of y are present and correct. For any x greater than or equal to 1, all values in `readBack` are 0.

I'm unsure at this point where I'm going wrong. If I iterate through `twoDarray` it certainly has data for all values of x. Why is the data zero'd out when x is greater-than-or-equal-to 1?

Answer (score 2):

With C arrays, &twoDarray actually is a pointer to the array **and** the first element afaik, so its just putting the first element into the NSData. Maybe write each element (of x, not x and y) into an NSData object, and then combine them

```
NSData *data1 = ... 
NSData *data2 = ... 
NSMutableData *completeData = [data1 mutableCopy];
[completeData appendData:data2];
```

Then i guess the reason when you are reading in your data the way you are doing it, the elements are zero'd because new NSData objects have zero'd memory to begin with, so if you have an NSData that is X*n and you only are putting in X*1 worth of data, the rest will be 0's

as @macmoonshine mentioned, can use [`appendData:length:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutabledata/1407704-appendbytes?language=objc) instead of creating temporary NSData objects for each element which will be more efficient

Comment: Writing the data to a temporary data object isn't necessary. You can use [`appendData:length:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutabledata/1407704-appendbytes?language=objc) instead.

Comment: ah yes, that will be better

Comment: Yeah, the iterative approach definitely works, and probably is acceptable. But I was hoping for a single operation to copy the entire block. I wonder, is a 2d C-array not contiguous and sequential in memory?

Comment: @Thunk yeah i dont think a 2d array is contiguous, only 1d, since a 2d array is basically just a 1d array full of pointers to other 1d arrays

Answer (score 1):

Your array is an array of pointers. For your approach it is easier to use an single array and transform the two-dimensional indexes to a one-dimensional index:

```
struct myStruct twoDarray[maxX*maxY];
// twoDarray[x][y] is equivalent to twoDarray[x * maxY + y]
```

You can read back your data analogously to writing it

```
[myData getBytes:&readBack length:sizeof(struct myStruct) * maxX * maxY];
```

Comment: so the working theory here seems to be that we simply can't add two dimensional C arrays to nsdata in one operation? Not sure I follow your math in the comment. With maxX = 56 and maxY = 40, I need a total of 2,240 slots. If x = 55 and y = 40, in your equation I get slot #3,120.